# What is an image uri? Image uri inside the listview

Tags: android

Can someone please explain to me what's an image uri? I have an android app with a listview that can attach an image, and that listview displays the imag uri. thanks

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI
its the link to the resource of your image (eg.: "@drawable/icon")

Answer (score 11):

URI is an address like: `http://www.google.com/image.png` it refers to the image somewhere.

It can also be a local address: `file:////something.png`

So you can attach a file that you don't have on your device and you don't want to download it.

Answer (score 3):

**URI or Uniform Resource Identifier is a compact sequence of characters that identifies an abstract or physical resource. It can be further classified as a locator, a name, or both.**

Basically URI (in some cases URL or URN) will point to the image location, or will be the name of the image (why not both?).

Let's take a look at some URI examples:

- https://stackoverflow.com/ (a URL because of the HTTPS protocol)
- ftp://ftp.is.co.za/rfc/rfc1808.txt (also a URL because of the
  FTP protocol)
- http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt (also a URL because of the
  HTTP protocol)
- ldap://[2001:db8::7]/c=GB?objectClass?one (also a URL because of the
  protocol)
- mailto:John.Doe@example.com
- tel:+1-816-555-1212
- telnet://192.0.2.16:80/ (also a URL because of the protocol)

Answer (score 0):

Basically it's just a string in which identifies some-type of web resource.