# Base64.encodeToString() not working in Android

Tags: java, android, encode

So i have a bitmap and now i want to convert it into an imageUri (or string),
i am using this code here but its just doesn't work instead of returning the imageUri its returning a long random text.

Here is my code :

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    saveBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, baos);
                    String path = Base64.encodeToString(baos.toByteArray(),Base64.DEFAULT);
```

And this is what i am getting :[image: Log.d]

Comment: That is the base64 encoded version of your image. Why did you expect a "imageUri"?

Comment: How can I get..the image uri from a bitmap...can you tell?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20429433/2970947

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Sorry guys, i thought Base64.encodeToString() will return me the imagePath, but i was wrong. Anyways i got the solution,

Here is the code that i have used,

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    saveBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, baos);
                    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),saveBitmap,"Title",null);
```

Answer (score 6):

Instead of `Base64.DEFAULT`, use `Base64.NO_WRAP`

```
String path = Base64.encodeToString(baos.toByteArray(),Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

Answer (score 5):

try below way, should be work

```
byte[] data = convert image in byte.
String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);


byte[] data = Base64.decode(base64, Base64.DEFAULT);
String text = new String(data, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

Base64.encodeToString() encodes the byte array in a string. This isn't your uri. Rather this is your image/bitmap in Base64. You can use suitable Base64.decode to get back the byte array.

To get uri, you can use some of the other options including
     Uri.fromFile(new File("your_file_path));

Comment: Please note i do not have a filePath , i just have a bitmap....anyways i got the solution (See my answer) . Appreciate your efforts..

Comment: Thanks for informing

Answer (score 0):

```html
try {
                    val imageStream: InputStream? = requireActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(mProfileUri)
                    val selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream)
                    val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
                    selectedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos)
                    val b = baos.toByteArray()
                    val encodedString: String = Base64.encodeToString(b,Base64.DEFAULT)

                    Log.d("check string" ,encodedString.toString())

                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
                
For kotlin use this code and this is running successfully image to base64 when upload image to server . just put image uri "imageStream" here thats it.
```